# How can one show the multiple integral $\int_{0}^{a} \int_{0}^{a} \frac{dx ~ dy}{(a^2+x^2+y^2)^{3/2}}= \frac{\pi}{6a}$ by hand?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals, multiple-integral

Mathematica gives the value of the  multiple integral 
$$
\int_{0}^{a} \int_{0}^{a} \frac{dx ~ dy}{(a^2+x^2+y^2)^{3/2}}=\frac{\pi}{6a}.
$$

See also [this result](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Integrate%5B1%2F%28a%5E2%2Bx%5E2%2By%5E2%29%5E%283%2F2%29%2C%7Bx%2C0%2Ca%7D%2C%7By%2C0%2Ca%7D%5D) from WolframAlpha:

> [image]

The question is how to show this by hand?

This is posted in the spirit of sharing some experience and to see how others would solve it. I am posting a solution below (now moved to the duplicate target).

Comment: It seems that there are some older posts about the same (or at least similar) integral: [Double Integral $\int_0^a\!\!\!\int_0^a\frac{dx\,dy}{(x^2+y^2+a^2)^\frac32}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1033129), [Solving $\iint \frac{1}{(x^2+y^2+1)^{3/2}} dx dy$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3000389) and [How to evaluate the integral ${\int\limits_0^{m_1} \int\limits_0^{m_2} }\frac{dx' dy'}{[(x-x')^2+(y-y')^2+25]^{\frac{3}{2}}}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1344304). Some tips on searching: [How to search on this site?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/29265)